# How many ways to put 15 people of three different jobs in 5 rooms with certain conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

We have 5 teachers, 5 engineers and 5 doctors. We want to put them in 5 rooms ( A B C D E )with the capacity of 3 people. In how many formations, there are at least two doctors in a room and two engineers in a room and two teachers in a room?

I thought maybe using the complement would help but there will be too many separate situations to consider. Like No two teachers and two doctors etc.

Comment: The key is realizing that each room can only fulfill only one constraint at a time

Comment: Could you please explain more? @Sudix

Comment: You can use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  Notice that if no room has two doctors, then each doctor must be assigned to a different room.

Comment: Thank you so much @N. F. Taussig